# How do I clone an array of objects in JavaScript but set values of new array to null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to duplicate my array, but have the new values set to null (or empty). The below works fine for cloning the array, but also copies the values:

```
this.userDetails = [this.userDetails[0], ...this.userDetails];

returns:
0: Proxy {reference: 'b2c00', start_date: '1989-01-22'…}
1: Proxy {reference: 'b2c00', start_date: '1989-01-22'…}
```

I want the values to be reset for the new item, eg:

```
0: Proxy {reference: 'b2c00', start_date: '1989-01-22'…}
1: Proxy {reference: '', start_date: ''…}
```

what is the best way to do this? thanks

A solution for those it might help:

```
const orig = this.userDetails[0];
const copy = {};
Object.keys(orig).forEach(prop => copy[prop] = null);
this.userDetails.push(copy);
```

Comment: the OP's  example does not feature any `null` value

Comment: __[this.userDetails[0], ...this.userDetails];__ this is just adding the first element twice in the same list, there is no cloning taking place

Comment: Also be aware that one is dealing with `Proxy` instances. Thus the biggest challenge most probably is to come up with an approach of **how to clone a proxy** and not ... *"How do I clone an array of objects"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you would do something like this:

```
const orig = {reference: 'b2c00', start_date: '1989-01-22'};
const copy = {};
Object.keys(orig).forEach(prop => copy[prop] = null);
console.log(copy) // { reference: null, start_date: null }
```

Or use the reduce function:

```
const copy = Object.keys(orig).reduce((acc, prop) => {
                 acc[prop] = null
                 return acc;
             }, {});
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger - You are correct but he asked to set all copied values to null which shallow copy won't do

Comment: sorry, of cause you're right ... beg my pardon ... I will erase my comment

Comment: thanks @PeterSeliger, your idea helped me find a solution. i've amended the question with an answer

Comment: @jkthompson83 ... the OP actually wanted to thank (upvote, accept) *David Biderman*

Answer (score -1):

```js
var obj = {
reference: 'b2c00',
start_date: '1989-01-22'
};
    
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

for (var prop in obj2) {
obj2[prop] = "";
}

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj2)
```